# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_machine_learning'

Tags: qiskit

Having problem with loading 'from qiskit_machine_learning.neural_networks import SamplerQNN', and it was fine yesterday.
Does anyone know what's happening?

BTW I use IBM Quantum Learning Lab, so I "guess" there's no install issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because Qiskit recently made changes to the Qiskit metapackage which affects the Qiskit library extras including qiskit-machine-learning. Now, all the extras are moved to be their own library, so to speak [[Reference]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#qiskit-0-44-0).

As of writing this answer, the Qiskit documentation has not been updated yet to reflect this change. So now, you can install the required package using

```
pip install qiskit-machine-learning
```

instead of

```
pip install qiskit[machine-learning]
```

You may refer to the [Github Repo](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-machine-learning#installation) for additional details.

This should fix any import-related issues.